# How to Transform the data in a .txt file for Electronic Fund Transfers

Tags: c#, asp.net, text

So at the moment our ERP/PSA software produces an EFT (Electronic Fund Transfer) .txt file which contains Bank and employee bank information which is then sent to the bank.

Problem is as follows the format to which the EFT File is currently being produced is US standard and not suitable to Canadian bank standards. But I have the required canadian bank standard format.

The format of the file is all about number of columns in a file and the number of characters they contain (if the data for the column doesnt reach the number of characters it is filled with spaces).

So I.e.

```
1011234567Joe,Bloggs      1234567
```

And for example lets say I try transform to Canadian Standard

```
A101Joe,Bloggs    1234567   1234567
```

Where for example "A" needs to be added to first line in the record.

I'm just wondering how to go about a task like this in C#

I.e.

Read in text file.
Line by Line parse data in terms of start and end of characters
Assign values to variables
Rebuild new file with these variables with different ordering and additional data

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to create a class to hold the logical data that is present in the file and have methods in this class for parsing the data from a given format and saving it back to a given format.

For example, assume the following class:

```
public class EFTData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RoutingNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public void FromUSFormat(string sLine)
    {
        this.Id = sLine.Substring(0, 3);
        this.RoutingNumber = sLine.Substring(3, 7);
        this.Name = sLine.Substring(10, 20);
        this.AccountNumber = sLine.Substring(30, 7);
    }
    public string ToCanadianFormat()
    {
        var sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(100);

        // Note that you can pad or trim fields as needed here
        sbText.Append("A");
        sbText.Append(this.Id);
        sbText.Append(this.RoutingNumber);
        sbText.Append(this.AccountNumber);

        return sbText.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can then read from a US file and write to a Canadian file as follows:

```
        // Assume there is only a single line in the file
        string sLineToProcess = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("usin.txt");

        var oData = new EFTData();
        // Parse the us data
        oData.FromUSFormat(sLineToProcess);
        // Write the canadian data
        using (var oWriter = new StreamWriter("canout.txt"))
        {
            oWriter.Write(oData.ToCanadianFormat());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my IDE open so my syntax might be a tad off, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.  Anyways, what fun would it be to give you the solution outright?

First you're going to want to get a list of lines:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = text.Split('\n');
```

You said that the columns don't have delimiters but rather are of fixed widths, but you didn't mention where the columns sizes are defined.  Generally, you're going to want to pull out the text of each column with

```
colText = line.Substring(startOfColumn, lengthOfColumn);
```

For each column you'll have to calculate startOfColumn and lengthOfColumn, depending on the positions and lengths of the columns.

Hopefully that's a good enough foundation for you to get started.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputPath);
var results = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    results.Add(string.Format("A{0}", line));
}
File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, results.ToArray());
```