# How to create a .EFT File?

Tags: c#

How to create a .eft in C#? how to group separator and file separator inside the .eft file?
as far as i know .eft is saving by hex. 
i don't know group separator and file separator character in C# and how to convert them.

Comment: eft is electronic fund transfer file.

Comment: See if this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529639/how-to-transform-the-data-in-a-txt-file-for-electronic-fund-transfers) helps

Answer (score 0):

Mayb this helps, its the file separator

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#9244;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x241c;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +241C
UTF-8 (hex)     0xE2 0x90 0x9C (e2909c)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10010000:10011100
UTF-16 (hex)    0x241C (241c)
UTF-16 (decimal)    9,244
UTF-32 (hex)    0x0000241C (241c)
UTF-32 (decimal)    9,244
C/C++/Java source code  "\u241C"
Python source code  u"\u241C"
```

here is the group separator

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#9245;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x241d;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +241D
UTF-8 (hex)     0xE2 0x90 0x9D (e2909d)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10010000:10011101
UTF-16 (hex)    0x241D (241d)
UTF-16 (decimal)    9,245
UTF-32 (hex)    0x0000241D (241d)
UTF-32 (decimal)    9,245
C/C++/Java source code  "\u241D"
Python source code  u"\u241D"
```